# Nginx + Supervisor + Gunicorn + Django + Celery - Security concerns

Tags: security, nginx, celery, gunicorn, supervisord

I am running a web server with nginx, followed by gunicorn to run a Django app with Celery.  All of the gunicorn processes and Celery workers are managed by Supervisor.  My question is, what are the best practices in terms of setting permissions for each of the processes in the stack?

Currently I am basically following defaults, and I'm pretty sure there's some parts that are unsecure here:

1. Nginx master process is root, worker processes run as www-data
2. Supervisor runs as root
3. Gunicorn is running as root (I tried to set it as another use, but the process would not start)
4. PostgresSQL and RabbitMQ run as their own users (postgres and rabbitmq)
5. I haven't set up Celery yet, but their docs say to not run as root

Which permissions could be tightened up, and what files do I have to ensure they have access to in order to work?

Comment: I have also found this answer on serverfault to be helpful: 
http://serverfault.com/a/357109

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supervisor will need to be root to start the other processes (like Nginx) with root privileges.  That should be fine because Supervisor shouldn't interact directly with external users or accept user input.

Gunicorn should be able run without privileges, you may have to change the owner of the unix domain socket it's using to be www-data instead of root.

Generally in web server scenarios you need root privileges to access files and open sockets on ports below 1024.  If your server can't access files, you should change their permissions rather than run with privileges.  You'll generally need privileges to open up port 80 or 443 which is why modern web servers start as root, bind to their port and then shed privileges to their running user of www-data or nobody.

In terms of other things you should consider, here's a quick list:

- Ensure your database queries are resistant to SQL injection
- Ensure your document root is well defined and you're not serving up more files than you intend.
- Minimize privileges your database accounts have (they probably don't need table drop and create, for example)
- Avoid any places in code where you're taking user input and executing or evaluating it